# aspNetDisabled class default system colors

Tags: asp.net, css, systemcolors

Where can I find the aspNetDisabled class default properties system color values?  A ddl/select control background property is not "grayed" out when ddl.Enabled=false.  For aesthetic purposes I want it to look similar to other disabled controls.

I can change the background of a DDL in the css with:

```
Select.aspNetDisabled
{
    background-color:ScrollBar;
}
```

Setting all background colors to the same value like this:

```
.aspNetDisabled
{
    background-color:ScrollBar;
}
```

[surprisingly but makes sense now] is not a solution.  Radio buttons and checkboxes have more than its "input area" grayed since the background for them consists of more than an input area.  A rb becomes a grayed out square with a grayed out circle. I have tried ever possible SYSTEM COLOR that is available in VS2010 style builder color picker and none of them match.  I can view the source and get the color there, but a hard coded value will not necessarily be identical on different machines.  I like the default functionality of the aspNetDisabled class and only need to override the background for ddl's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aspNetDisabled deafult grayed out system color is "ButtonFace [in .css and buttonface from source]!  I wrote a Javascript function to get the background color of a disabled TextBox.  I tried the same code yesterday, but failed because of browser specific Javascript functions.

Chrome did not like the property string I was passing to currentStyle[] - received an undefined property error:

```
var txtBx = $get('<%=txtBx.ClientID %>');
var prop = "background-color";  //also tried backColor and many other variations

strValue = txtBx.currentStyle[prop];
alert("strValue" + strValue);
```

The getComputedStyle method worked, but of course that is not what I wanted.  I ran the same Javascript using ie and was able to get the currentStyle[prop] value.

aspNetDisabled is simply a variable for a class/.css.  It would be nice to be able to see its values.  I searched the Framework and the "net" yesterday for any related .css files/classes and for the string "aspNetDisabled".  The only matches I encountered were aspNetDisabled in WebControls.cs and a WebAdminStyle.css under the 4.0 dir.  I also tried to use the debugger, but could not find the style properties for "txtBX" as I expanded each layer.

I guess writing Javascript a function to loop through all properties for each type of "disabled" control would accomplish that.  There is probably a way to write a .net class to find all properties and their values of a .css class too.

It is unclear to me why the background color of a DDL does not get modified when disabled...

I hope this helps someone!